# Flutter app not able to connect to the internet via WIFI - why?

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app which checks if there is an active internet connection and stops the user if there is no connection. Here is my code

```
  try {
    final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
      print('connected');
      // move to main screen

    }
  } on SocketException catch (_) {
    print('not connected');
    // alert user there is a problem
  }
```

Now I am getting some feedback from some users that when they are on a WI-FI network they get the alert message (="not connected") while if they are on a cellular network they are able to move into the main screen (="connected"). I am not able to replicate the problem using my device, ie on Wi-Fi I am able to move to the main screen.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't have an empty catch, there could be some information in the error that would help.

Comment: Hi Phil, which information should I try to capture?

Comment: can you connect in debug mode?

Comment: In the "not connected" block, you're passing the error as _, you should handle that if there's actually an error.

Comment: the problem is that if I debug with my devices I do not get any error. The error happen only on very few devices. This is a production app and I received this complaint from 2 users out of 4k (one android and one iPhone)